Can't configure Hive Metastore client jars in Spark 3.5.1
I need to configure my Spark 3.5.1 application so it uses specific version of Hive Metastore client.
I read in the documentation that I can use:
spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars
spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars.path

So I tried this:
spark.sql.hive.metastore.version: "2.3.9"
spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars: "path"
spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars.path: "/usr/lib/spark/hive/jars/*"

I previously copied the jar hive-metastore-2.3.9.jar to the folder /usr/lib/spark/hive/jars/*.
The error I get is:
24/12/06 15:34:10 INFO ApplicationMaster: Unregistering ApplicationMaster with FAILED (diag message: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/api/AlreadyExistsException
    [...]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.AlreadyExistsException
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:592)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1.doLoadClass(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:281)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1.loadClass(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:270)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    ... 86 more
)

So I think I miss some jars in that folder (even if AlreadyExistsException is in hive-metastore).
Does anyone have a list of jars that must be in the folder? The documentation says:

...This classpath must include all of Hive and its dependencies,
including the correct version of Hadoop. The provided jars should be
the same version as spark.sql.hive.metastore.version. These jars only
need to be present on the driver, but if you are running in yarn
cluster mode then you must ensure they are packaged with your
application.

so I think I miss some of the artifacts in the filesystem.

(1) You can use JDK's jdeps tool to see all the dependencies of a jar.  (2) Validate that class indeed exists in a jar using  jar tf /path/to/your/hive-metastore.jar | grep "AlreadyExists" since there are multiple profiles to build a jar from the source you've referenced. (3) Try using hive-standalone-metastore.jar instead of hive-metastore.jar.

I noticed AlreadyExistsException extends org.apache.thrift.TException so definitely I have to review the jars

I think you have to specify the full installation hive lib path, not just copy the metastore jar to a dir you specified.
Here is my testing steps for hive 3.1.3:

Setup the environment

cd /home/spark/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3
export SPARK_HOME=$(pwd)
export PATH=$PATH:${SPARK_HOME}/bin


Setup conf/spark-defaults.conf

spark.sql.hive.metastore.version        3.1.3
spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars           path
spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars.path      /home/hive/apache-hive-3.1.3-bin/lib/*


Copy commons-collections-3.2.2.jar to /home/hive/apache-hive-3.1.3-bin/lib/*

cp $SPARK_HOME/jars/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar /home/hive/apache-hive-3.1.3-bin/lib/*

if you don't do this, you will get the following exception:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1.doLoadClass(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:274)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1.loadClass(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:263)        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)        
... 64 more


Run spark-sql to test it, and you will see the schema version is 3.1.0.

/home/spark/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3# spark-sql
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
24/12/10 23:58:22 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2024-12-10T23:58:24,886 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf - Found configuration file null
Hive Session ID = 020e5eba-c9b9-46d2-8fec-30b825ca3b24
.
.
.
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql - Using direct SQL, underlying DB is DERBY
2024-12-10T23:58:26,270 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore - .
.
.
.
Version information not found in metastore. metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 3.1.0
.
.
.
Spark master: local[*], Application Id: local-1733846303879
spark-sql (default)>

